# removing unmatched lines with SED

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to remove everything but 3 separate lines with specific matching pattern and leave just the 3 lines I want

Here is my code;

```
sed -n '/matching pattern/matching pattern/matching pattern/p' > file.txt
```

Comment: That's almost correct. But `/pattern/pattern/pattern/` isn't meaningful as a statement. You want `/pattern/p; /pattern/p; /pattern/p`.

Comment: grep is much intuitive. normally sed is better for something requiring text editing.

Comment: post some testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple commands on the same line, you need to separate the commands by a `;`:

```
sed -n '/matching pattern/p;/matching pattern2/p;/matching pattern3/p' file
```

Alternatively you can put them onto separate lines:

```
sed -n '/matching pattern/p
        /matching pattern2/p
        /matching pattern3/p' file
```

Beside that, you can also use regex alternation:

```
sed -rn '/(pattern|pattern2|pattern3)/p' file
```

or (*better*) use `grep`:

```
grep -E '(pattern|pattern2|pattern3)' file
```

However, this might get messy if the patterns getting longer and more complicated.

Comment: i would propose using `-e` option to make independent expression more explicit.

Comment: Good point. I've thought about that too but don't wanted to add more alternatives. Also `awk` can be used. :)

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk '/pattern1/ || /pattern2/ || /pattern3/' filename
```

I think it's cleaner than alternatives.

Comment: Plus 1. I also like awk for searching for various patterns at the same time. I even get more and more used to use `awk` instead of grep all the time, even if there is just one search pattern -> just for the case I want to add something later. However, I would still say that `grep` is the *cleanest* way to search for patterns in a file. Believe me, there are tons of guys who don't understand the above `awk` cmd. Sad but true. However if `grep` is used, at least everybody knows that the command is about searching in a file.

Comment: + grep supports a lot of useful options like `-i`, `-w`, `-F`.

Comment: @hek2mgl I think exactly the lack of magic options is what makes awk cleaner.  .

Answer (score 2):

### Sed with Deletion

There's always more than one way to do this sort of thing, but one useful sed programming pattern is using alternation with deletion. For example:

```
# BSD sed
sed -E '/root|daemon|nobody/!d' /etc/passwd

# GNU sed
sed -r '/root|daemon|nobody/!d' /etc/passwd
```

This makes it possible to express ideas like "delete everything *except* for the listed terms." Even when expressions are functionally equivalent, it can be helpful to use a construct that most closely matches the idea you're trying to convey.

Comment: It is worth knowing that `|` matches itself inside a regexp i.e. a pipe, unless the `-E` (`-r` GNU sed) is set whereas when either of those options are set or preceded by `\ ` i.e. `\| ` when it becomes the meta character meaning alternation.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/pattern1/b;/pattern2/b;/pattern3/b;d' file
```

The normal flow of sed is to print what remains in the pattern space after processing. Therefore if the required pattern is in the pattern space let sed do its thing otherwise delete the line.

N.B. the `b` command is like a `goto` and if it has no following identifier, it means break out of any further sed commands and print (or not print if the `-n` option is in action) the contents of the pattern space.

Comment: Thanks for all your Help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
sed -n '/\(pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3\)/p' file > newfile
```